# Questionable notation for date for year month day time

Tags: python, excel, vba, datetime, image-processing

I am learning to use [imageplot](http://lab.softwarestudies.com/p/imageplot.html).

Their [documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zkeik0v2LJmi1TOK4OxT7dVKJO7oCmx_fNP8SYdTG-U/edit?hl=en_US) states that:

> “Year_month,” “Label_Place,” and “Title” columns are the examples of
>   metadata which often comes with images. The first is year and month of
>   each van Gogh painting which art historians determined using his
>   letters. To arrive at the values in this column, we used Excel to
>   convert months numbers 1-12 to decimal numbers 1-10, and then added
>   these converted numbers to years. (To make this process more clear, we
>   provide years and months separately in “year” and “month” column.)
>   “Label_Place” column contains names of the key places where the artist
>   lived and worked; the five labels correspond to typical categories
>   used in discussing and exhibiting van Gogh’s works (for instance, the
>   Vincent van Gogh museum also presents an overview of artist career
>   using same five periods.)

Here's an example of this weird Year_Month notation:

```
+------------+------+-------+
| Year_Month | Year | Month |
+------------+------+-------+
| 1881.834   | 1881 |    11 |
| 1881.834   | 1881 |    11 |
| 1881.834   | 1881 |    11 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
+------------+------+-------+
```

Does anyone know how to interpret what the .834, .5838 mean? Is this some kind of standard notation? Is it possible to include not just the month and year, but also day of the month and time in this notation? I'm looking for a solution in either python or Excel.

**How do I implement this notation for datetime in excel or python?**

I did a distinct year_month, year, month on one of the files provided by ImagePlot, and got these:

```
+------------+------+-------+
| Year_Month | Year | Month |
+------------+------+-------+
| 1884       | 1884 |     1 |
| 1885       | 1885 |     1 |
| 1887       | 1887 |     1 |
| 1889       | 1889 |     1 |
| 1890       | 1890 |     1 |
| 1884.0834  | 1884 |     2 |
| 1885.0834  | 1885 |     2 |
| 1887.0834  | 1887 |     2 |
| 1888.0834  | 1888 |     2 |
| 1889.0834  | 1889 |     2 |
| 1890.0834  | 1890 |     2 |
| 1884.1668  | 1884 |     3 |
| 1885.1668  | 1885 |     3 |
| 1886.1668  | 1886 |     3 |
| 1887.1668  | 1887 |     3 |
| 1888.1668  | 1888 |     3 |
| 1889.1668  | 1889 |     3 |
| 1890.1668  | 1890 |     3 |
| 1883.2502  | 1883 |     4 |
| 1884.2502  | 1884 |     4 |
| 1885.2502  | 1885 |     4 |
| 1886.2502  | 1886 |     4 |
| 1887.2502  | 1887 |     4 |
| 1888.2502  | 1888 |     4 |
| 1889.2502  | 1889 |     4 |
| 1890.2502  | 1890 |     4 |
| 1884.3336  | 1884 |     5 |
| 1885.3336  | 1885 |     5 |
| 1887.3336  | 1887 |     5 |
| 1888.3336  | 1888 |     5 |
| 1889.3336  | 1889 |     5 |
| 1890.3336  | 1890 |     5 |
| 1885.417   | 1885 |     6 |
| 1886.417   | 1886 |     6 |
| 1887.417   | 1887 |     6 |
| 1888.417   | 1888 |     6 |
| 1889.417   | 1889 |     6 |
| 1890.417   | 1890 |     6 |
| 1884.5004  | 1884 |     7 |
| 1885.5004  | 1885 |     7 |
| 1886.5004  | 1886 |     7 |
| 1887.5004  | 1887 |     7 |
| 1888.5004  | 1888 |     7 |
| 1889.5004  | 1889 |     7 |
| 1890.5004  | 1890 |     7 |
| 1882.5838  | 1882 |     8 |
| 1883.5838  | 1883 |     8 |
| 1884.5838  | 1884 |     8 |
| 1885.5838  | 1885 |     8 |
| 1886.5838  | 1886 |     8 |
| 1887.5838  | 1887 |     8 |
| 1888.5838  | 1888 |     8 |
| 1889.5838  | 1889 |     8 |
| 1883.6672  | 1883 |     9 |
| 1884.6672  | 1884 |     9 |
| 1885.6672  | 1885 |     9 |
| 1886.6672  | 1886 |     9 |
| 1888.6672  | 1888 |     9 |
| 1889.6672  | 1889 |     9 |
| 1883.7506  | 1883 |    10 |
| 1884.7506  | 1884 |    10 |
| 1885.7506  | 1885 |    10 |
| 1886.7506  | 1886 |    10 |
| 1887.7506  | 1887 |    10 |
| 1888.7506  | 1888 |    10 |
| 1889.7506  | 1889 |    10 |
| 1881.834   | 1881 |    11 |
| 1883.834   | 1883 |    11 |
| 1884.834   | 1884 |    11 |
| 1885.834   | 1885 |    11 |
| 1887.834   | 1887 |    11 |
| 1888.834   | 1888 |    11 |
| 1889.834   | 1889 |    11 |
| 1884.9174  | 1884 |    12 |
| 1885.9174  | 1885 |    12 |
| 1886.9174  | 1886 |    12 |
| 1887.9174  | 1887 |    12 |
| 1888.9174  | 1888 |    12 |
| 1889.9174  | 1889 |    12 |
+------------+------+-------+
```

When trying to process a file with values similar to xxxx.xxxx (as above):

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Contents of the entire file can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/n5tdfMx0).

Comment: Pretty close to `str(Year) + '.' + str((Month - 1)/12)`.  (Adapted from @Kevin's answer below, adjusted for an off by one error.)

Comment: I don't see an answer below. @StevenRumbalski is this some kind of known notation?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, I thought it might be something like that, too. But if the documentation is to be believed, month 1 should be converted to the decimal 1. Unless they meant to write "we used Excel to convert months numbers 1-12 to decimal numbers 0-9" or something.

Comment: @Kevin: I believe 1-12 was mapped to 0-11 and then divided by 12.  See the file [here](https://github.com/culturevis/imageplot/blob/master/sample_files/van_gogh/van_gogh_data.txt).  The rounding is off, so the answer is not exactly right.  When the month is January the Year_Month field is just the year by itself.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski please see edit, i've used the file you linked to and got the distinct of the 3 columns.

Comment: @Kevin i added a few more details please see edited post

Comment: Given `Year_Month` as a string:  `Year = int(float(Year_Month)); Month = int(float(Year_Month) % 1 * 12) + 1`.

Comment: how would i add day of month and time?

Comment: @Yuck:  Day of month and time are not given in the data file.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski but if they are integers, dont you think i could just use the same math as you did above and add days and hours?

Comment: By the way guys, I eliminated that bad datarow, and it accepted the data file and drew this nice picture out of about 2000 images: http://screencast.com/t/kppSHFtTrWV  however it still does not answer my question about why the heck they are using this horrible notation